# Change Column Name in MATLAB

Tags: excel, matlab, text-files

USING MATLAB:

I have an excel file:

```
California Texas Florida
123        333   234
222        567   123
234        324   334
```

I want to CREATE or write to a text file with the change column names but yet keep the same data.

So the desire output is:

```
CA     TX     FL
123    333    234
222    567    123
234    324    334
```

Thanks,

Amanda

Comment: You'll first need to save the Excel file as a text file (tab-delimited recommended) and read it in MATLAB. THen, in MATLAB, you'll need to systematically replace those strings to the ones you'd like. Or as Peter L. said, you can correct them by hand if you're doing this once or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is easy using MATLAB's [`xlsread`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlsread.html), but it would be equally as easy just copying and pasting the abbreviations over the names, unless you've got a lookup table and tons of values to do.

In that case:

```
[data,colNames] = xlsread('FileName.xlsx');
newColNames = {'CA','TX','FL'};
output = [newColNames;num2cell(data)];
xlswrite('NewFileName.xlsx',output);
```